# How to delete backed files only from original storage device?

Tags: files, filesystems, data

I have a backup of an SD card but have not yet deleted the original files to free up space. Now, they got mixed up with new files.

How do I delete all files that are already backed up (same file name and file size) from the original SD card, without manually deleting each file manually and without messing around with date ranges?

Comment: What you are describing is an archive, not a backup. (it can not be a backup, if there is no original).

Comment: What ever you do, make a backup first (it will go wrong).

Comment: You may be able to do something with `find` to find the archived files, then mutate the names to point to the originals and `rm`.

Comment: Just an idea: you might be able to use `rsync` between the original and the backup locations to find a list of changed files: https://serverfault.com/questions/618735/can-i-use-rsync-to-create-a-list-of-only-changed-files . Once you have that list, you can temporarily move those files elsewhere and remove everything else from the original location.